# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: but its with a variable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making this program just for test some modules, but this problem hapened:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1000, 500'(the varible) I actually realy don't know why this is happening and I tryed to transform the string variable to a int variable but nothing hapened. The scrypt:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
win = Tk()
win.title('autoclass.enter V1')
win.geometry('500x500')

def start():
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click(coord1.get())
    time.sleep(5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1225, 600, duration = 1) 
    pyautogui.click(1225, 600) 
    keyboard = Controller()
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(8)
    keyboard.type(name.get())
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

myLabel2 = Label(win, text='hello')
myLabel2.place(x=50, y=10)

myLabel1 = Label(win, text='here goes youre name')
myLabel1.place(x=218, y=50)

myLabel3 = Label(win, text='here goes the cords')
myLabel3.place(x=220, y=100)


name = Entry(win, width=30)
name.place(x=178, y=70)

coord1= Entry(win, width=30)
coord1.place(x=178, y=120)

button = Button(win, text='start', command=start)
button.place(x=50, y=300)
win.mainloop()
```

the problem is coming from the variable of cord1.
thanks!

Comment: can you place a comment in the code where the error is and what the error reads

Comment: Better, post the python traceback so we can see the exact error text, the line it was on and the call stack.

Comment: i believe the error is because `pyautogui.click(coord1.get())`. You have given input in form of '1000, 500' but it is a string u need to pass x and y cordinates separately like `pyautogui.click(coord1.get(),coord2.get())` where `coord1` is a single integer and `coord2` is also a single integer. Just my assumption since there is no error code given. and i think theyr looking for a file named '1000, 500' to click to and mayb that is y the error is produced

Comment: I seriously doubt pyautogui and pynput are compatible with tkinter.

Comment: I tried to separate the coord1 to coord1 and coord2, but other error apeared:      
`needleFileObj = open(needleImage, 'rb') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Answer (score 0):

Actualy I needed to transform the string of the     coords.get()    to int, like this
`a= coords.get()`
`b= int(a,0)`
`pyautogui.click(b)`
thaks to all